# Translucency in a Tile Based Lighting System

Tags: java, light, translucency

I have a lighting system already working and (mostly) functional. I'm trying to implement translucency so that certain blocks (like water) only remove a fraction of light passing through them, and it works, but it stops working at the **whole number limit** of the lightmap (in my case, 20).

This is what it looks like:
[image: translucency glitch]

and here is my code:

```
for(int x=0;x<mapX;x++){
for(int y=mapY-1;y>-1;y--){
    try{
       if(map[x][y] instanceof LightSource)
                    lightmap[x][y]=19;
       else{
          else{
                if(x-1>-1&&lightmap[x][y]<lightmap[x-1][y])
                     lightmap[x][y]=lightmap[x-1][y]-map[x][y].translucency;
                if(x+1<lv.map.length-1&&lightmap[x][y]<lightmap[x+1][y])
                     lightmap[x][y]=lightmap[x+1][y]-map[x][y].translucency;
                if(y+1<lv.map[0].length-1&&lightmap[x][y]<lightmap[x][y+1])
                     lightmap[x][y]=lightmap[x][y+1]-map[x][y].translucency;
                if(y-1>0&&lightmap[x][y]<lightmap[x][y-1])
                     lightmap[x][y]=lightmap[x][y-1]-map[x][y].translucency;
            }
      }
  }catch(Exception e){}
}
}
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?
Is there another system I could use to support transparency?
Can anybody tell me at least why this is happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working?" Stops working in what way?

Comment: You're eating any `Exception` that may be thrown.  The first step in troubleshooting this problem is logging the exceptions or using a simple `e.printStackTrace()`.  Once you've confirmed there are no exceptions then focus on the code.

Comment: I really dont think the exceptions are the problem. They exist to prevent the script from failing at the edges of the map. If I print the stack trace, it will just give me a myriad of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s around the edges.

Comment: And it stops working by setting the light values of the water to 0 in places they shouldn't be, as shown by the graphic.

Comment: It's a `float[][]`. The value is cast to `int` before being output as light. `translucency` is also a `float`, being 1 for most blocks and 0.2 for water.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary exception catching. I put a .printStackTrace() in the one that is necessary (that wraps around the whole script), but an Exception isnt even thrown in this case, because it's buffering the entire lightmap at `GameState` initiation. That `catch` is only necessary  for updating the lightmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing
    `for(int y=mapY-1;y>-1;y--)`
to
    `for(int y=0;y<mapY-1;y++)`.
Absolutely no idea why that worked, though. Also, I'm afraid this same system might yield similar results if the light was coming from the bottom up instead of the top down. Haven't tested that yet, but it would make sense since all I did was change the order of the cellular automata.